# Orthogonal columns imply orthogonal rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

The original question is: [Column Vectors orthogonal implies Row Vectors also orthogonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52717/column-vectors-orthogonal-implies-row-vectors-also-orthogonal/52719#comment2156994_52719)

A counterexample with zero entries is given in one post. However, my question is whether pairwise orthogonal columns **with no zero entries** imply pairwise orthogonal rows?

Comment: @WillJagy if the matrix is square and has zero determinant, then one of the columns has all 0s because any set of nonzero orthogonal vectors is linearly independent.

Comment: The only case when it is *generally* true is when the columns are ortho*normal* and the matrix is square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  Here's a counterexample:
$$
\pmatrix{1&2\\-1&2}
$$

Comment: Is there a systematic way of constructing these counterexamples with any n*n square matrices with nonzero pairwise orthogonal columns?

Comment: Yes.  Start with an orthonormal basis of $n$ column-vectors, and multiply one of them by $2$.  At least, I think that should work.